# Jquery how merge multiple files in one main.js file with the same scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I created a main.js file that contains all the JQUERY functions I need.
Unfortunately the functions, events, ajax calls etc are becoming so many and then I would like (in developing) to split the main.js
file in multiple files (user.js, cars.js, initialize_plugin.js etc, but in the same scope) and merge in a single file main.js file when at release.

main.js

```
$(function() {

    var globalVar = "foo";

    // MANAGE USERS

    function addUser () { .. }

    $("addUser").on("click", function() {
        ...
        $(this).data("value", globalVar);

    });

    ...

    // MANAGE CARS

    function addCar () { .. }

    $("addCar").on("click", function() {
        ...
        loadFancyboxPlugin()
    });


    // INITIALIZE EXTERNAL PLUGINS

    function loadFancyboxPlugin() {
        $( "[data-fancybox]" ).fancybox({});
    };

    $( ".date" ).datepicker();

    ...

});
```

How could I do that? And how could I join them? Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a perfect job for RequireJS - http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: Ones you get into multiple files, I recommend to look into namespacing make sure you don't accidentally overwrite a function or variable in another file. In a simple example, each file can start with `var myApp = myApp || {};` , then using the revealing module pattern add the required sub-namespace to each file similar to: `var myApp.user =  (function () { return { addUser: addUser}})();` where `: addUser` refers to your `function addUser...` inside the file above the `return` statement. That way you can just load the required files using RequireJs as mentioned above but also keep safe.